# Expect block in chef does not taking the passwords

Tags: bash, weblogic, expect, chef-recipe

I have wrote a chef recipe which will take the passwords and provide some output. So i am using bash block to call the expect and take the passwords using send command, The code will looks like below -

```
bash "Update Schema #2 Passwords" do
    user "#{prod_user}"
    group "#{usergroup}"
    code <<-EOH
    export RETAIL_HOME=#{retail_home}
    cd #{retail_home}/orpatch/#{product_wallet}
    /usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ./update-rase01_db.sh
    expect "Enter the username to associate with rase01_db (this can be the existing username or a new username):"
    send "#{schema2_username}\r"
    expect "Enter your secret/Password:"
    send "#{schema2_password}\r"
    expect "Re-enter your secret/Password:"
    send "#{schema2_password}\r"
    expect "Enter wallet password:"
    send "#{wallet_password}\r"
    expect eof'
    EOH
end
```

When i am running this recipe. I am getting the following output -

```
bash[Update Schema #2 Passwords] action run
      [execute]                      
                Note: when prompted for your secret/Password, enter the NEW value you want to use.

                Enter the username to associate with rase01_db (this can be the existing username or a new username): RASE01

                Running /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/client_1/bin/mkstore -wrl /u01/projects/rase/retail_home/orpatch/orase_wallet -modifyCredential rase01_db RASE01

                Oracle Secret Store Tool : Version 12.1.0.2
                Copyright (c) 2004, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

                Your secret/Password is missing in the command line
                Enter your secret/Password:   Welcome1

                Re-enter your secret/Password:
                Enter wallet password:
                oracle.security.crypto.core.CipherException: Invalid padding string (or incorrect password)
      - execute "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20170120-4085-jw5ynw"
```

So my understanding is During the first prompt which is "Enter your secret/Password" Its taking the password and just provide the value as {Enter Key stroke} for the next prompt which is during  "Re-enter your secret/Password:" So the passwords are incorrect  and getting failed.

Please give me some suggestions or option to how to handle this.

**Work a round to avoid Expect block in chef** -

```
bash "Update Schema #2 Passwords" do
    user "#{prod_user}"
    group "#{usergroup}"
    code <<-EOH
    export RETAIL_HOME=#{retail_home}
   cd #{retail_home}/orpatch/#{product_wallet}
    echo #{schema2_username} >> passwd
    echo #{schema2_password} >> passwd
    echo #{schema2_password} >> passwd
    echo #{wallet_password} >> passwd
    ./#{rase_schema_update} < passwd
    rm -rf passwd
    EOH
end
```

But still i am looking for a solution why i am not able to get the passwords with expect.

Comment: From the output above looks like the contents of wallet_password contain invalid chars contains an empty string. Can you verify?

Comment: @thun: Thanks for the response. The passwords contains the actual string. I even tried printing the value on console i got the password from data bags. Currently i did a work a around to make it work .